# Rename label in row 0

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm having problems renaming a label, nothing happens when I apply rename()
My brain has been fried for days but am I missing a dumb detail or why nothing happens?
Also, what's going on with the indices X1, X2...
When I try to call df.EDUCATION it says the data frame doesn't have the attribute 'EDUCATION' so I have to call df.X3 which is of no use to me... how can I exchange those indices for the actual labels?

Thanks in advance.

`df.rename({'ID':'QQQ'},axis='columns')`

```
0           ID  LIMIT_BAL   SEX EDUCATION   
1            1  20000       2   2   
2            2  120000      2   2
3            3  90000       2   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens because you don't assign the result of rename. Rename is not an inplace operation. You should do

```
df = df.rename({'ID':'QQQ'},axis='columns')
```

Comment: that didn't work either. The only line behind that is the data importation, I haven't done anything before that.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using. It definitely works in 1.2.1 and above

Comment: I looks like it is the 1.1.5 version. I will update it, I used ```df, df.columns = df[1:] , df.iloc[0] and that finally put the ID, SEX, etc as labels, however I still couldn't use rename(), I will try after updating